# Run specific jest project

Tags: jestjs, lerna

I'm setting up a lerna monorepo with jest, I'm using jest's projects like so: `projects: ['<rootDir>/packages/*']`.

Running tests work as expected, however, I'm not sure how can I run a specific project? Say I have:

```
/packages
  jest.config.js
  /core
      jest.config.js
  /blog
      jest.config.js
```

Currently `jest` runs tests in both packages using their specific configs, however, I'm not sure how can I tell jest to just run tests in one of those packages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call jest with the name of a test that you want to run. You can also use just parts of the path to the test, or even a regular expression. So in your case, you could run tests in the `core` package like this:

```
jest packages/core
```

Answer (score 27):

Assuming you want to do this with Jest's `projects` property:

As of Jest [v26.1.0](https://github.com/facebook/jest/releases/tag/v26.1.0), you can now run selected `projects` with Jest by doing the following:

```
jest --selectProjects myproj
```

This will find any "project" in your `jest.config.js` by it's `displayName` value.

See:

- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7542
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/8612
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/releases/tag/v26.1.0

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is exactly what i was searching for. Agree with @taystack. This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no clean way of doing it from the CLI (see https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6189), but you can use https://github.com/rogeliog/jest-watch-select-projects to achieve it in watch mode